# SSH Key Exchange with alternate user

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel7, public-key-exchange

So I am using RHEL 7. I have two servers with the following user accounts

1. root (obvious)
2. admin

I want the setup to work in the following manner.

passwordless SSH from server 1 to server 2 using the `admin` user, but the SSH initiation is done from the `root` user always.

We are not allowed to do ssh key exchange for the `root` user, but the app that we are working with uses root to ssh to the other nodes.

I hope I am making sense here :)

SSH using `root` user to server2, but internally it should use `admin` user's key and connect to server2 using admin user.

I have tried to confiure `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and added host/user config there, now I am able to run `ssh server2` from `root` user and it connects to server2 using my defined admin user in the ssh_config file but it prompts for a password every time which I don't want.

Key exchange with `admin` is already done and tested to be working fine when I issue ssh as `admin` user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the world did this get a -1? Please leave constructive criticism and not just a -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` you need to add the key to use, something like this:

```
Host srv2
 User admin
 IdentityFile /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
```